# How to let a Lambda perform DynamoDB operations?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I think I have a pretty common scenario but I couldn't find a condensed guide on how to achieve my goal. I am developing an Alexa Skill and have the following:

```
Lambda function: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:lambda1
```

Currently the Alexa Skill is working fine with the Lambda doing a simple task. The Lambda's Execution Role is:

```
arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/service-role/lambda1-role-rp2z9bjn
```

I now want to add DynamoDB to my Lambda (Node.js). I created the following:

```
IAM user: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/user1
DynamoDB table: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/T1
```

How do I now hook up everything together, that is, to let the Lambda function perform read/write operations on `T1`? Is the IAM user even necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the IAM User.

Instead, add DynamoDB permissions to the IAM Role being used by the Lambda function. For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "dynamodb:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789012:table/T1"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Lambda function will then be permitted to use the table.